Circle with initials in person field Microsoft lists
I have a person field column in Microsoft lists where some entries will have many persons. Maybe up to 20 people.
Only two of them have an actual picture. For the rest of them it will show the generic placeholder for a picture. It does not look that good. Is it a way to show circles with initials instead?
I use this JSON:
    {
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "children": [
    {
      "forEach": "personIterator in @currentField",
      "elmType": "div",
      "style": {
        "width": "32px",
        "height": "32px",
        "overflow": "hidden",
        "border-radius": "50%",
        "margin": "2px",
        "display": "=if(loopIndex('personIterator') >= 4, 'none', '')"
      },
      "children": [
        {
          "elmType": "img",
          "attributes": {
            "src": "=@currentWeb + '/_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx?size=S&accountname=' + [$personIterator.email]",
            "title": "[$personIterator.title]"
          },
          "style": {
            "position": "relative",
            "top": "50%",
            "left": "50%",
            "width": "100%",
            "height": "auto",
            "margin-left": "-50%",
            "margin-top": "-50%",
            "display": "=if(length(@currentField) > 4 && loopIndex('personIterator') >= 3, 'none', '')",
            "vertical-align": "baseline"
          }
        },
        {
          "elmType": "div",
          "attributes": {
            "title": "=join(@currentField.title, ', ')",
            "class": "ms-bgColor-neutralLight ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary"
          },
          "style": {
            "width": "100%",
            "height": "100%",
            "text-align": "center",
            "line-height": "30px",
            "font-size": "14px",
            "display": "=if(length(@currentField) > 3 && loopIndex('personIterator') == 3, '', 'none')"
          },
          "children": [
            {
              "elmType": "span",
              "txtContent": "='+' + toString(length(@currentField) - (3))"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

